# Spark Dataframe sql in java - How to escape single quote

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark-core, spark-sql, Spark-hive 2.10(1.6.1), scala-reflect 2.11.2. I'm trying to filter a dataframe created through hive context...

```
df = hiveCtx.createDataFrame(someRDDRow,
                    someDF.schema());
```

One of the column that I'm trying to filter has multiple single quotes in it. My filter query will be something similar to

```
df = df.filter("not (someOtherColumn= 'someOtherValue' and comment= 'That's Dany's Reply'"));
```

In my java class where this filter occurs, I tried to replace the String variable  for e.g commentValueToFilterOut, which contains the value "That's Dany's Reply" with

```
commentValueToFilterOut= commentValueToFilterOut.replaceAll("'","\\\\'");
```

But when apply the filter to the dataframe I'm getting the below error...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.103] failure: ``)'' expected but identifier
s found

    not (someOtherColumn= 'someOtherValue' and comment=  'That\'s Dany\'s Reply'' )
                                                                ^                                          
    scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.SqlParser$.parseExpression(SqlParser.scala:49)
    org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.filter(DataFrame.scala:768)
```

Please advise...

Answer (score 0):

We implemented a workaround to overcome this issue.

**Workaround:**

Create a new column in the dataframe and copy the values from the actual column (which contains special characters in it, that may cause issues (like singe quote)), to the new column without any special characters.

```
df = df.withColumn("comment_new", functions.regexp_replace(df.col("comment"),"'",""));
```

Trim out the special characters from the condition and apply the filter.

```
commentToFilter = "That's Dany's Reply'"
commentToFilter = commentToFilter.replaceAll("'","");
df = df.filter("(someOtherColumn= 'someOtherValue' and comment_new= '"+commentToFilter+"')");
```

Now, the filter has been applied, you can drop the new column that you created for the sole purpose of filtering and restore it to the original dataframe.

```
df = df.drop("comment_new");
```

If you dont wnat to create a new column in the dataframe, you can also replace the special character with some "never-happen" string literal in the same column, for e.g

```
df = df.withColumn("comment", functions.regexp_replace(df.col("comment"),"'","^^^^"));
```

and do the same with the string literal that you want to apply against

```
    comment_new       commentToFilter = "That's Dany's Reply'"
    commentToFilter = commentToFilter.replaceAll("'","^^^^");
    df = df.filter("(someOtherColumn= 'someOtherValue' and comment_new= '"+commentToFilter+"')");
```

Once filtering is done restore the actual value by reverse-applying the string litteral

```
df = df.withColumn("comment", functions.regexp_replace(df.col("comment"),"^^^^", "'"));
```

Though It's not answer the actual issue, but someone having the same issue, can try this out as a workaround.

The actual solution could be, use sqlContext (instead of hiveContext) and / or Dataset (instead of dataframe) and / or upgrade to spark hive 2.12.

experts to debate & answer

**PS: Thanks to KP, my lead**